# c# / openxml merge of word documents to one, fails --closed--

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I have to merge several word documents with a small c# console application. So far so good. The documents are generated in arcplan. Around 30 files are generated, but somehow some documents are corrupted, but still shows me Content. 
If I merge now all files which are correct my document is fine but if i have a corrupted file in my bunch of files any corrupted generates an empty page. I debugged it of course, but i dont see anything going wrong which explains the empty page.

the arguments are like this: 
"C:\temp\Report_C_01.docx" "C:\temp\Report_D_01.docx" "C:\temp\Report_E_01.docx"

here´s my Code:

```
public static void Merge(params String[] filepaths)
    {
        String pathName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepaths[0]);
        subfolder = Path.Combine(pathName, "Output\\"); //Wird für den gemergten File benötigt

        if (filepaths != null && filepaths.Length > 1)
        {
            WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@filepaths[0], true); //Wordfiles werden geöffnet
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            for (int i = 1; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
            {
                String altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + i;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@filepaths[i], FileMode.Open);
                chunk.FeedData(fileStream);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk altChunk = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                //new page, if you like it...
                mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page } )));
                //next document
                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            }
            mainPart.Document.Save();
            myDoc.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                String fileNameWE = Path.GetFileName(filepaths[i]);
                File.Copy(filepaths[i], subfolder + fileNameWE);
            }

            foreach (String fp in filepaths)
            {
                File.Delete(fp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nur 1 Argument");
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Best regards
Christian

Comment: When you open a corrupt docx does it give you an error? I recall that a log file is generated too that provides info on what the problem is.. Or no error and the docx just comes out looking weird?

Comment: You should try the [Package Explorer](https://packageexplorer.codeplex.com/) as it can point why exactly your document is corrupt

Comment: When i open it in word it gives me the error: "unknown mistake /word/document.xml line 1" when i look it up in the productivity tool i see there are 3 unkown Elements, but if i compare it to a not corrupted file i dont see any difference in the XML tree. After the document is open it Looks fine. Just after i merged it with my program it gets into an empty page

Ok I will try it out with the Package Explorer, thanks

Comment: No sorry it didnt help. XML is fine, so i dont know where the corruption is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. It seems word cannot merge different Formats in one Document. So if you have 2 documents with a footer and other 3 without it just won´t work. Obviously it can happen that some customers have these kind of issues; at least the Code is fine